# Split and append liste in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, split, append

Ok so here is what I am trying to do. I have a List A which has the folowing elements. I want to modify this list A such that every element in A shall be preceded with its character count. for example, a1 becomes 02a1 and aa1 becomes 03aa1 so on and so forth.

```
A = "a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,aa1,ab1,ac1" 
A = A.split(',')
A.append('bb1')
print(A)
for evry_element in A:
   q = [len(evry_element)]
   for ev_el in evry_element:
       q.append(ord(ev_el))
   print(q)
```

This code is working for me but the result I get is this:

```
['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'aa1', 'ab1', 'ac1', 'bb1']
[2, 97]
[2, 97, 49]
[2, 98]
[2, 98, 49]
[2, 99]
[2, 99, 49]
[2, 97]
[2, 97, 50]
[2, 98]
[2, 98, 50]
[2, 99]
[2, 99, 50]
[3, 97]
[3, 97, 97]
[3, 97, 97, 49]
[3, 97]
[3, 97, 98]
[3, 97, 98, 49]
[3, 97]
[3, 97, 99]
[3, 97, 99, 49]
[3, 98]
[3, 98, 98]
[3, 97, 99, 49]
```

But I want the result to be in a single string like this:

```
A_new = [2, 97, 49,2, 98, 49,2, 99, 49,2, 97, 50,2, 98, 50,2, 99, 50,3, 97, 97, 49,3, 97, 98, 49,3, 97, 99, 49,3, 97, 99, 49]
```

What Should I do?
I hope did my best in explaining what I want to do.

Comment: Howdy! Please see the [mcve] definition in the Help Center -- a good question involving code shows us an example we can run to see your *exact* problem, with no unrelated errors (so you should be using real Python syntax, not pseudocode).

Comment: What do you wish to do if the string is longer than 99 characters?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your desired output is. Is that... a list with one single massively long string inside?

Comment: Also, is there any chance of any of these strings containing non-ascii characters? If so, you should encode the strings to bytes *before* getting their length.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes, thats exactly what I want. i want to make a list with one single massively long string and then convert it into bytearray.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```py
A = "a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,aa1,ab1,ac1" 
A = A.split(',')
A.append('bb1')
print(A)
q = []
for evry_element in A:
   q.append('0' + str(len(evry_element)) + evry_element)
print(q)
```

Though I'm not sure why you decided to append `bb1`.